# Multiples AddOnSuccessListener?

Tags: c#, android, firebase, xamarin, google-cloud-firestore

Xamarin.Android C#: I have several `void` where I need to have the `AddOnSuccessListener`, the problem is that they all go to the same `OnSuccess`.

How can I have 3 or more `AddOnSuccessListener` with different `OnSuccess` for each void?

Example of voids:

> query.Get (). AddOnSuccessListener (this);

- 

> database.Collection ("Users"). Document (DocID) .Get ().
> AddOnSuccessListener (this);

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Get()` call returns a task. While a task can have multiple listeners, you can't chain them together like you're trying.

So you'll want to capture the task, and then call `AddOnSuccessListener` multiple times.

```
var task = database.Collection("Users").Document(DocID).Get();
task.AddOnSuccessListener(this);
task.AddOnSuccessListener(...);
task.AddOnSuccessListener(...);
```